# Systemd service: Failed to issue method call: Unit service failed

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, php

I am trying to make a custom service in my VPS. However, it doesn't let me run it. It says the following. I am not sure what is going on but when I run it on my Ubuntu laptop it works properly. What could be the problem?

**sudo systemctl start websocket.service**

```
Failed to issue method call: Unit websocket.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status websocket.service' for details.
```

**cat /lib/systemd/system/websocket.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=php webSocket
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
User=root

Type=simple
ExecStart=/webs.sh
TimeoutStopSec=20
KillMode=process
Restart=always
RestartSec=2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=websocket.service
```

**cat /webs.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/php /server.php
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          webSocket
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: php webSocket
# Description:       php webSocket
### END INIT INFO
```

**I have tried `systemctl daemon-reload` but I get the following**:

```
Attempted to remove disk file system, and we can't allow that.
Ignoring /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/ssh.service -> /lib/systemd/system/ssh.service for systemd deputy init
Ignoring /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/rsyslog.service -> /lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service for systemd deputy init
Ignoring /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/bind9.service -> /lib/systemd/system/bind9.service for systemd deputy init
Ignoring /etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/phpsessionclean.timer -> /lib/systemd/system/phpsessionclean.timer for systemd deputy init
```

I also rebooted the server but nothing, Can anyone give me some hint of what is going on?